# Prove the derivative of $f(x)=\left( \left| x \right| \right) ^{3}$ exist.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

i got a problem with this exercise.

I need to prove the derivative of this function: $f(x)=\left(  \left| x \right|  \right) ^{3}$ exist.

Well, i make via definition:$\lim _{h\rightarrow 0}{\frac { \left(  \left| x+h \right|  \right) ^{3
}- \left(  \left| x \right|  \right) ^{3}}{h}}$

I know this: $|x|^3=|x|^2|x|=x^2|x|$
Now, $\lim _{h\rightarrow 0}{\frac { \left(  \left| x+h \right|  \right) ^{3
}- \left(  \left| x \right|  \right) ^{3}}{h}}$ = $1/2\,{\frac { \left| x \right| x \left( 5\,\overline{x}+x \right) }{
\overline{x}}}$

But i think my answer is too bad, please help ):

Comment: What is $\bar{x}?$ The derivative outside $0$ exists because it's just $x^3$ or $-x^3$, and in zero it also exists because $\lim_{h\to 0} |h^3|/h=0$. By the way, it is more common to write $|x|^3$ or $|x^3|$ then $(|x|)^3$.

Comment: @PeterFranek is module

Answer (score 3):

We know that $$|x|^3 =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x^3  & \mbox{if } x \geq 0 \\
  (-x)^3 & \mbox{if } x < 0
 \end{array}
\right.$$
so we know that our function is trivially differentiable everywhere except at $0$.
Let's prove, by definition, that our function is also differentiable at $0$.
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|h|^3}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}h|h|=0.$$
If I skipped one too many steps, feel free to ask me to explain in the comments.

Comment: Can i abbreviate this always? $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|h|^3}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}h|h|=0.$ @Matija Sreckovic

Comment: How do you mean abbreviate? The only step I think I skipped here is (this would go after the first equality sign)$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|h|^3-0}{h}$

Comment: @Bvss12 The key is $|h|^3=h^2|h|$.